# How to remove the middle periods in section headings?

Tags: sectioning

I never use more than nine chapters, sections, subsections, or subsubsections. Therefore, I would like to remove the middle periods (but not the final period) in my section heading, as follows, both in the main text and the Table of Contents. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: yes, it is trivial. You can simply redefine \thesection etc. But do you really want to go against tradition?

Comment: Is this only for your own use? Because everybody else will be quite puzzled...

Comment: Please tell us how which document class you employ and how you define `\thechapter`, `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, etc at present.

Comment: Actualy, adding a period at the end is a bit unusual in itself.